# Auto-select a value from a drop down list in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, dropdown, imacros

I want to create a Chrome extension but I can't make an automatic selection. How can I select a value from a dropdown in Google Chrome? I can't do it automatically via jQuery and Javascript but it works with imacros. Is there a way to do it with jQuery or javascript or others in a Chrome Extension?

This is my code which does not work, using jQuery:

```
$('#categorisation_1>option:eq(5)').attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
$('#categorisation_1').find('option:eq(3)').attr('selected', true);
```

And also using plain JS:

```
document.getElementById('categorisation_1').setAttribute('size', 3);
```

This way work using imacros

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:categorisation_1 CONTENT=%1:<SP>Object
```

Comment: using java? why would you use java in a chrome extension? That'd be like using diesel in your tesla

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm assuming that's supposed to be JavaScript. I've edited it.

Comment: Hum, OK, interesting Scenario... Well, it works indeed in iMacros (by `Value` + `Name` + `Option Number` in the DDLB, => well, look at how it is implemented in iMacros then... :idea: // (You can download the '.xpi' File for the [iMacros for FF v8.9.7](http://download.imacros.net/imacros_for_firefox-8.9.7-fx.xpi) Add-on for example, rename it to '.jar' and decompile/unzip it using '7zip' and find out how the `TAG` Command implements the `CONTENT` Param with `%`/`$`/`#` Values for DDLB's...) // And correct Spelling is "JavaScript" + "iMacros" btw...!

Comment: @chivracq, I tried to do what you advised me but I can't frankly it's too complicated for me thank you anyway

Comment: Hum, yep, don't want to sound "snarky" but you seem to lack some basic JS Knowledge indeed, so building a Browser Addon/Extension sounds like an "ambitious" Project then... // But hum, looking at your pure JS Attempt, the `setAttribute()` looks irrelevant to me, Source of your DDLB Element not posted, but I would expect you need some Syntax like `document.getElementById('categorisation_1').value=3`... :idea: